# provided $f( x+1) =\ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(\frac{n+x}{n-2}\right)^{n}$, what is f(x)?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

$$
f( x+1) =\ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(\frac{n+x}{n-2}\right)^{n}
$$

Here is one of the solution from my workbook:
$$
 \begin{array}{l}
f( x+1) \ =\ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left[\left( 1+\frac{2+x}{n-2}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right]^{n\left(\frac{2+x}{n-2}\right)} =\ e^{2+x} =e^{1+( x+1)}\\
f( x) \ =\ e^{1+x}
\end{array}
$$

but is a bit preplexing for me :(

Comment: What is the part you struggle with ?

Comment: angryavian has already posted an answer, but, I would mention that,

$$\lim_{x\to a}(1+f(x))^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)}$$ whenever $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$

Comment: @Tuvasbien I have let $k\ =\ \frac{n-2}{2+x}$, and $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left[\left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k}\right]^{\frac{n}{k}} =\ e^{n\left(\frac{2+x}{n-2}\right)}$, then struggle with how did it obtain $e^{2+x}$.But I'm confused by the last step of the answer of angryavian now, as same as QuasarChaser.

Comment: You wrote $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}...=...$ with something depending on $n$ in the right hand side which is not possible. Following @Doobius hint, $$\left(1+\frac{2+x}{n-2}\right)^n=\exp\left(n\log\left(1+\frac{2+x}{n-2}\right)\right)$$ then you can use $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}=1$ with $t=\frac{2+x}{n-2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $$\frac{n+x}{n-2} = 1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}$$
from rearranging.

Then they use the following fact $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^k = e$$
which implies
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x}} = e.$$
By continuity, we can raise both sides to the $2+x$ power.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x} \cdot (2+x)} = e^{2+x}.$$

Finally, note that
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x} \cdot \frac{n}{n-2}(2+x)}
&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x} \cdot (2+x)}
\cdot
\underbrace{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{2}}_{=1}
\\
&=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x} \cdot (2+x)}
\\
&= e^{2+x}.\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm confused by the last part- from the expression $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x} \cdot \frac{n}{n-2}(2+x)}$$ how did you obtain the following: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x} \cdot (2+x)} \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{2}$$ The exponent was $\frac{n}{n-2}$, how did it become 2?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's more detailed :D.

I try to follow the solution carefully.
the fact
$$
\lim _{k\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k} =e
$$
Can I just replace k with $k\ =\ \frac{n-2}{2+x}$ ?
$$
\lim _{\frac{n-2}{2+x}\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x}} =e
$$
and how can I replace $\frac{n-2}{2+x}\rightarrow \infty $ with $n\rightarrow{}∞$, then
$$
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2+x}} =e
$$

Comment: @QuasarChaser If you simplify the exponents, it's basically $a^n = a^{n-2} a^2$.

Comment: @QuasarChaser

change the provided
$$f( x+1) =\ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(\frac{n+x}{n-2}\right)^{n}$$
to
$$f( x+1) =\ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( 1+\frac{1}{\frac{n-2}{2+x}}\right)^{n}$$

the exponents is n, and
$$^{\frac{n-2}{2+x} \cdot \frac{n}{n-2}( 2+x) \ =\ n\ =\ n-2\ +\ 2\ =\ \frac{n-2}{2+x} \cdot ( 2+x) \ +\ 2}$$

and just follow the last part.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\left(\frac{n+x}{n-2}\right)^{n}=\left(\frac{(n-2)+(x+2)}{n-2}\right)^{n}=\left(1+\frac{x+2}{n-2}\right)^{n}$$ Taking logarithms
$$\log(y)=n \log\left(1+\frac{x+2}{n-2}\right)\sim n \frac{x+2}{n-2}=\frac{n}{n-2}(x+2)\sim x+2$$ So
$$y=f(x+1)\sim e^{x+2} \implies f(x)=e^{x+1}$$

Comment: What is meaning of ~ ? and how is $ \log(1 +\frac{x + 2}{n-2}) = \frac{x + 2}{n-2} $ , if you please. Thanks

Comment: $\sim$ means *approximately equal to*